# Will hashmap compares references also before comparing with equals while putting a same key in hashmap?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap

I have a problem in which i override the equals method and returning false everytime.
If I put the same object twice in hashmap,according to equals implementation,it will return false and duplicate entries with same object exists,but it is overriding existing object only.So will it compare adress reference also before comparing with equals?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapOverrideequals {

    public MapOverrideequals(int anshu) {
        this.anshu = anshu;
    }

    int anshu;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<MapOverrideequals, String> m = new HashMap<MapOverrideequals, String>();

        MapOverrideequals mm = new MapOverrideequals(1);
        MapOverrideequals mm1 = new MapOverrideequals(1);

        m.put(mm, "ji");
        m.put(mm, "ki");
        //m.put(mm1, "ansh");

        for (Map.Entry<MapOverrideequals, String> m1 : m.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m1.getKey().anshu + "  " + m1.getValue());
        }

    }

}
```

Output:1 ki

Comment: you putting mm twice, so the last entry will overwrite the first

Comment: As a matter of fact it will. But your implementation of `equals()` violates the reflexivity requirement of its [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-). That is, for all `x`, `x.equals(x)` must be true. What are you trying to do? There is probably a better way to approach it.

Comment: @StuartMarks-This is just an interview question asked,I am trying to do nothing :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
```

It checks for hash and key reference equality.